# Passing kickstart parameters when creating VM's on Proxmox 2.x

Tags: linux, virtualization, libvirt

I'm trying to find a way to pass kernel parameters when creating VM's from the command line on Proxmox 2.1.

I'd like to be able to batch create VM's using the QM command, and pass kickstart parameters, similar to libvirt -x option.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

From qm man page:

> args: ... 
>          Note: this option is for experts only. It allows you to pass arbitrary arguments to kvm, for example:
>            args: -no-reboot -no-hpet

AFAIC, used it to set `-serial` KVM params like this:

> args: -serial unix:/var/run/qemu-server/104.serial,server,nowait

It should work with `-append` KVM option too but not tested it yet.